# Enabling localizations in Unity3d game for ios

Tags: iphone, ios, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

We've implemented localization to our Unity3d game with the help of the Unity3D plugin, the language is defined when loading and  the required language substitutes the default one (from xml). But when assembling for ios, ItunesConnect thinks that our game supports only English. What should we do to make it clear that we have localizations?

Comment: You have asked 7 questions, and you haven't accepted a single answer so far. Also, you're abusing the "xcode" tag. This is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You must manually enter the supported game/app languages on ITunes Connect.

Note from iTunes Connect:

> You can only add new languages if your app version is in an editable
>   state. To add new languages, you must submit a new app version from
>   the App Summary module or reject this version.